How do I get Backblaze B2 to respond with Access-Control-Allow-Origin?
I'm trying to fetch an image using JavaScript from a Backblaze bucket that is set to allPrivate.
I have a correct authorization code that works if I fetch the image like this:
echo '<img src="' . $_SESSION["downloadUrl"] . '/file/' . $bucketName . '/' . $file[0] . '?Authorization=' . $_SESSION["authorizationToken"] . '" />';

However, it fails when I try to use javascript:
const myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "<?php echo $_SESSION["authorizationToken"]; ?>");

const response = await fetch("<?php echo  $_SESSION["downloadUrl"] . '/file/' . $bucketName . '/test/test.avif'?>" , {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeaders
} );

if(response.ok) {
    const blob = await response.blob(); // Convert to a blob for use as an image
    const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob); // Create a local URL for the blob

    // Display the image
    b2.src = imageUrl;
} else {
    console.error('Error fetching image:', response.statusText);
}

The problem is that Backblaze isn't adding the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the options/preflight request. I have set the B2 CORS rules using the command line. This is what my CORS rules currently look like for this bucket:
"corsRules": [
  {
      "allowedHeaders": [
          "authorization",
          "x-bz-file-name",
          "x-bz-content-sha1",
          "x-bz-info-author"
      ],
      "allowedOperations": [
          "b2_upload_file"
      ],
      "allowedOrigins": [
          "https://example.com"
      ],
      "corsRuleName": "uploadRules",
      "exposeHeaders": [
          "x-bz-content-sha1"
      ],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  },
  {
      "allowedHeaders": [
          "range",
          "referer",
          "authorization",
          "sec-ch-ua",
          "sec-ch-ua-mobile",
          "sec-ch-ua-platform",
          "user-agent"
      ],
      "allowedOperations": [
          "b2_download_file_by_id",
          "b2_download_file_by_name"
      ],
      "allowedOrigins": [
          "https://example.com"
      ],
      "corsRuleName": "downloadRules",
      "exposeHeaders": [
          "x-bz-content-sha1",
          "access-control-allow-origin"
      ],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]

I think I have it all set up correctly, but for the life of me I can't work out how to get B2 to send the access-control-allow-origin header. What am I missing? Does B2 support preflight requests?

After reading this page it says what I have been trying to do is impossible:
Because browsers are specifically mandated to strip user-headers from CORS requests, it is not possible to use the Authorization header in download requests from private buckets when those requests come from a browser.
https://www.backblaze.com/docs/cloud-storage-cross-origin-resource-sharing-rules#cors-on-private-buckets

As you say, @Castles, you can't use the Authorization header from JavaScript in the browser. The way to do this is to create a presigned URL on the server side, and render that into the web page.
For example, with the AWS SDK for PHP:
$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => 'my-bucket',
    'Key'    => 'testKey'
]);

$request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');

// Get the actual presigned-url
$presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();

You could alternatively use the Backblaze B2 Native API b2-get-download-authorization operation to get an authorizationToken that you can pass as a query parameter to GET the file, but there are some key differences between the two mechanisms:

Creating an S3 presigned URL does not require an API call - it's essentially an HMAC operation involving the application key, application key ID, URL, etc. b2-get-download-authorization is a Class C API call that requires a round-trip to B2, and incurs a cost if you call it more than 2,500 times per day.
The S3 presigned URL applies to that exact URL only. The B2 authorizationToken applies to a prefix, so if you get an authorizationToken for the pets prefix, you can use it to download pets/kitten.jpg, pets/puppy.jpg, etc.

